# i cant use node modules package

Tags: javascript, django, frontend

i have a js file:

`<script type="module" src="{% static 'admin_panel/assets/js/sendAxios.js' %}" >`

I use it in this way:
`import axios from "axios";`
But it gives the following error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

When I chnage to :
`import axios from '../../../node_modules/axios'`;
It gives me the following error
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/node_modules/axios net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I always had these problems for import and require commands..
How can I use node modules of a package?

Answer (score 0):

use this 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.3/axios.min.js in your html and remove import/require from your js code.